# Get all selects after a current select element in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a table like this with multiple selects in very row:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="selectA" id="selectA">
....
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="selectB" id="selectB">
....
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="selectC" id="selectC">
....
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="selectA2" id="selectA2">
....
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="selectB2" id="selectB2">
....
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="selectC2" id="selectC2">
....
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="selectA3" id="selectA3">
....
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="selectB3" id="selectB3">
....
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="selectC3" id="selectC3">
....
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What I want to do is, when a select element changes, I want to get all select elements in the same row after the changed select element and change something with them as well.

So if selectA changes, I want to get selectB and selectC. If selectB changes, I want to get selectC. And so on. How to do that with jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextAll().find('select')...
});
```

i.e. take the element's `.parent()` (which will be the `<td>`), then for all of its following siblings `.nextAll()`, `.find()` all `<select>` elements within them.

Answer (score 1):

There are many jquery plugins that facilitate creating cascading dropdowns, which, in a nutshell, is what you want to achieve.

Here's a google search on ["cascading dropdown jquery"](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=cascading+dropdown+jquery&aq=1&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=cascading+dropdown); pretty much every result is a jQuery plugin :)

Comment: I would like to do it without a plugin. Isn't it possible with nextUntil() or some other function? Basically what I want to do is when a select element changes, set first option as selected for all select elements after it in the same row.

Comment: Well, it seems you sort of know the answer to your question :) I didn't know about `nextUntil()` but it looks like a good candidate. Is it with the jquery selector that you're having trouble?

Comment: Well, yes. But I think I've figured it out. I have posted an aswer. It seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you all the selects that are in the same row:

```
$("table select").change(function(){
    var $select_mates=$('select', $(this).closest('tr'));
});
```

If you don't want the element itself:

```
$("table select").change(function(){
    var $me=$(this);
    var $select_mates=$('select', $me.closest('tr')).not($me);
});
```

My solution uses the [jQuery Selector Context](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/24/understanding-the-context-in-jquery).

**EDIT:** Now I recognized I haven't seen `after a current select element` :). Let's see:

```
$("table select").change(function(){
    var $me=$(this);
    var $select_mates=$('select', $me.closest('tr'));
    var $select_after_mates=$select_mates.slice($select_mates.index($me)+1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification of the Alnitak solution would be to bind the event handler on table level instead, so that you end up with only one function bound doing the job:

```
$('table').change(function(event) {
    $(event.target).parent().nextAll().find('select')...
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>i would try something like</strike>

```
//"obj" being your <select> HTML element
jQuery(obj).parent().find("select").not(obj);
```

**UPDATE**

I know the answer is already there but i thought for completeness I'd add a fix:

```
//"obj" being your <select> HTML element
// .parent().parent() gets the row 
// .find("select" finds all the selects contained somewhere in that row.
// .not(obj) removes your current <select> 

jQuery(obj).parent().parent().find("select").not(obj);
```

Comment: This will only find `select`s in the same `td`.

Comment: Ah your right I Should have been looking for the parent `<tr>` first!.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this works, I've finally figured out how to do this:

```
$("table select").change(function(){
    $(this).parent().nextUntil().find("select option:first").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

Comment: Isn't the selector supposed to be used as `nextUntil()` parameter? why the extra `find`?

Comment: technically you want `.nextAll()` rather than `.nextUntil()`, although the no-args version of the latter is equivalent - see my answer.

Comment: This means every select is going to be bound to an event handler. I'd rather bind a listener on the tr element and then match next selects using event.target property.